# What is the difference between "<inp somecommand" and "somecommand <inp"?

Tags: shell, io-redirection

On any Unix shell, both the forms `<input.txt cat` and `cat <input.txt` seem to work exactly the same. Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no difference between them. See [the POSIX shell command language specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_10_02), which makes no distinction between a redirection before or following a simple command. (For compound commands, the specification only requires that the shell support redirections at the end).

Redirections at arbitrary points *within* a simple command are not something the POSIX sh specification requires support for; however, in shells such as bash where they are allowed, these too are syntactically equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference if `somecommand` is a simple command.

If it's a loop, the form with the redirection preceding the command is a syntax error:

For example, this:

```
while read line ; do echo "$line" ; done < /etc/motd
```

will print the contents of `/etc/motd` (handy to know if your system is so badly hosted that you can't execute the `cat` command), but this:

```
< /etc/motd while read line ; do echo "line" ; done
```

gives a syntax error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
```

This is for bash; other shells might behave differently.

Comment: Not just bash -- it's a clear reading of POSIX that compound commands are only required to support redirections at the end.